# Kind of a concatenation for 2 hashes

Tags: javascript

There are a few method calls in a js file looking like:

```
$("#id_1").someMethod({
  //some common hash values
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2",

  // some unique has values
  someKey1: "value123",
  someKey2: "value444"
})

// and so on
```

You see the idea: a few methods those have some common hash values (those the other method have) and some unique hash values those are different for each method.

How do I make a function which will have all the same hash values in it and will receive some additional hash values as an argument to be able to simplify the code?

**UPDATE**: Although using jquery is ok, I'm curious about achieving it without jquery.

Comment: You might want to retag as `jquery` since it looks like that's what you're using.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of what you want, including a second method with those duplicated hash values you mention, and ideally including what you would _prefer_ the code to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) what you are looking for?

```
var commonValues = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2"
};

$('#id').someMethod($.extend({
    someKey1: "value123",
    someKey1: "value444"
}, commonValues));
```

You should keep in mind that in this example the shared values with the same keys will overwrite the unique ones. If this is not the desired behavior, you need to provide an empty object as the first argument to `$.extend()`:

```
$.extend({}, commonValues, {
    /* unique values */
};
```

In case if `someMethod()` is of your own, and you are happy to modify it, you can move this logic inside:

```
someMethod: function(values) {
    values = $.extend({}, commonValues, values)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)?

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but it sounds like something like this.  Note that `extend` will modifiy the first parameter.

A non-jquery implementation might look as follows:

```
function addDefaults(overrides, defaults) {
  for(var prop in defaults)
    if(!(prop in overrides))
      overrides[prop] = defaults[prop];
  return overrides;
}
```

Here, `addDefaults(specific, general)` is roughly equivalent to `$.extend({}, general, specific)`, however it alters the `specific` object.  A version that supports multiple arguments and does not alter any is a little longer:

```
function addDefaults() {
  var retval = {}, arg;
  for(var i=arguments.length-1; i >=0; --i) 
    for(var prop in arg=arguments[i])
        retval[prop] = arg[prop];
  return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet:

```
function concat(a, b) {
  // Shallow copy
  var c = $.extend(b, a);
  return c;
}
```

Example usage:

```
common = {
      key1: "value1",
      key2: "value2"
};

$("#id_1").someMethod(concat(common, {
  // some unique has values
  someKey1: "value123",
  someKey2: "value444"
});
```

If you need a deep copy it should be not hard to modificate it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for something like this:

```
var commonValues = {
    key1 : "value1",
    key2 : "value2"
};

function helperFunc(additionalOptions) {
    $("#id_1").someMethod($.extend({}, additionalOptions, commonValues));
}

helperFunc({ someKey1: "value123", someKey2: "value444" });
```

[$.extend docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can take a look at someone else's implementation of `extend`, for example [Underscore's _.extend](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-76), and make your own.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used the expression "how do I MAKE a function", I assume that `someMethod` is a function that you wrote. In that case you can let the function accept two arguments, one for the common keys and one for the unique keys. Then you can use the `bind` function to bind your common keys object to the function:

```
var obj = {};

obj.someMethod = function(commonKeys, uniqueKeys){
    console.log(commonKeys);
    console.log(uniqueKeys);
};

var newFunction = obj.someMethod.bind(obj, {key1: 1, key2: 2});

newFunction({ukey1: 1, ukey2: 2});
```

With this way you create a new function, that you can call only with your unique keys while the common keys are provided automatically.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uGX22/4/)**